# How to Build Graph Using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8. I would like to use Java stream to build a graph.
For example, I have 2d array **edges** [[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[2,3,1]]. Each element in the array **edges**[i] = [ui, vi, weighti]. I use dictionary to represent my graph.

**Normal Java**

```
Map<Integer, List<int[]>> graph = new HashMap<>();
for(int[] edge: edges){
    graph.computeIfAbsent(edge[0], x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new int[]{edge[1], edge[2]});
    graph.computeIfAbsent(edge[1], x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new int[]{edge[0], edge[2]});
}
```

Is there any way using stream to do the exact same code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the for loop by a `Stream.forEach` method like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<int[]>> graph = new HashMap<>();
Arrays.stream(edges).forEach(edge -> {
    graph.computeIfAbsent(edge[0], x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new int[]{edge[1], edge[2]});
    graph.computeIfAbsent(edge[1], x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new int[]{edge[0], edge[2]});
});
```

Or you could use a `toMap` Collector like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<int[]>> graph = new HashMap<>();
graph.putAll(Arrays.stream(edges).collect(Collectors.toMap(edge -> edge[0], edge -> Arrays.asList(new int[] {edge[1], edge[2]}))));
graph.putAll(Arrays.stream(edges).collect(Collectors.toMap(edge -> edge[1], edge -> Arrays.asList(new int[] {edge[0], edge[2]}))));
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)